# Android MMS Parsing

Tags: java, android, mms, mms-gateway

In one of my application, I have to **parse** the **MMS** content. I am able to get the **encoded MMS content** in the form of **byte[]**. Now I have to decode this byte[] and need to extract all the content based on their content types and header values. But I am struggling here. I don't know how to start decoding...

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you have the content in byte[] so you can try this:

```
byte[] buffer;
String incomingNumber = new String(buffer);
int indx = incomingNumber.indexOf("/TYPE");
if(indx>0 && (indx-15)>0){
   int newIndx = indx - 15;
   incomingNumber = incomingNumber.substring(newIndx, indx);
   indx = incomingNumber.indexOf("+");
   if(indx>0){
   incomingNumber = incomingNumber.substring(indx);
}
```

you can continue to parse like this.

Comment: I am not getting your idea. would you explain in detail or any related link?

Comment: are you fetching the MMS content from the inbox or you are parsing the data for newly arrived mms thru listener.?

Comment: thru listener(BroadcastReceiver)

Comment: then the above code is perfectly working as I have done this. you can check this link for more clearity:http://lovingandroid.blogspot.com/2011/07/mms-listener.html

Comment: it extract only number,but i need to extract the body content of the mms.For example if the received mms consists the images as well as text,then have to extract image separately and text separately.

Comment: you are getting the whole msg in incomingNumber ...put debugger over incomingNumber and look for it's content format and extract it accordingly...

Comment: i don't know how to put debugger.will you explain it?