# Java pattern on hex code

Tags: java, android, hex, design-patterns, mms

I've the following hexadecimal code that I want to parse. For curious people, this is a MMS packet.

```
e306246170706c69636174696f6e2f766e642e7761702e6d6d732d6d65737361676500af84b4818c82986e323333426178773042737549684d008d918918802b33333631313131313131312f545950453d504c4d4e0086818a808e02271088058103093a8083687474703a2f2f772e732f6158585842737549684d00
```

Detailed version is here:

```
e3 // Wsp transactionId
06 // Push type
24 // Length of the content type field and headers
6170706c69636174696f6e2f766e642e7761702e6d6d732d6d657373616765 // application/vnd.wap.mms-message 
00 // Null terminated
af84 // X-Wap-Application-ID
b481 // ?
8c82 // X-MMS-Message-Type:m-notification-ind 
986e323333426178773042737549684d00 // Transaction id random with seed
8d // MMS version
91 // 1.1
89 // From
18 // Length of from
80 // Address present
2b3333363131313131313131 // Sender phone number
2f545950453d504c4d4e // /TYPE=PLMN
00 // Null terminated
8681
8a // Message class
80 // Personnal (81=Ad, 82=Informational, 83=Auto)
8e // Message size
02 // Size will be coded on 2 bytes
2710 // 10000 bytes
88 // X-Mms-Expiry
05 // Field size
81 // Relative date format
03 // Time will be coded on 3 bytes
093a80 // Seconds
83 // X-MMS-Content-Location 
687474703a2f2f772e732f6158585842737549684d // Url to the server
00 // Null terminated
```

I need to get the phone number which `2b3333363131313131313131` in my hex code and the url to the server which is `687474703a2f2f772e732f6158585842737549684d`.
I'm working in Java for Android. I'm nearly sure I need to use pattern but I don't understand how it works.

I've done the following piece of code (which obviously, doesn't work):

- PhoneNumber pattern:

  ```
  String number = hexCode.replace("^89([a-f0-9])00$", "$1");
  number = number.substring(6, number.length() - 22);
  // Number should be equal to 2b3333363131313131313131
  ```
- Url pattern

  ```
   String url = hexCode.replace("^83([a-f0-9])00$", "$1");
   url = url.substring(2, url.length() - 2);
   // Url should be equal to 687474703a2f2f772e732f6158585842737549684d
  ```

Could you help me to make these patterns work ?

Edit:
I'm able to do the job WITHOUT patterns, but I don't think this is the best solution to be used.

```
// Try to find the pattern "http"
if (pduS.indexOf("68747470") > -1)
{
    String url = pduS.substring(pduS.indexOf("68747470"), pduS.length() - 2);
    Log.e(">>>>>>", "Url: " + convertHexToString(url));
}

// Try to find the pattern "/TYPE=PLMN"
if (pduS.indexOf("2b") > -1 && pduS.indexOf("2f545950453d504c4d4e") > -1)
{
    String shortPdu = pduS.substring(0, pduS.indexOf("2f545950453d504c4d4e"));
    String number = pduS.substring(shortPdu.lastIndexOf("2b"), pduS.indexOf("2f545950453d504c4d4e"));
    Log.e(">>>>>>", "Number: " + number);
    Log.e(">>>>>>", "Number: " + convertHexToString(number));
}
```

Comment: Is the position of `PhoneNumber` and `URL` always fixed ?

Comment: Try this answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334244/android-mms-parsing. Its not an exact solution but works.

Comment: Those parts aren't fixed. That's why the pattern is required.

Comment: Why not parse the entire code left to right, wrap it in a class, then use whatever data sections you need?

Comment: Parsing is what I ask...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone needs the answer to my question, here are the patterns to use:

```
Number: ^2b[0-9abcdefABCDEF]+2f545950453d504c4d4e$
Url: ^68747470[0-9abcdefABCDEF]+00$
```

And here is the application to the MMS Pdu:

```
public String getNumber(String pduString)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^2b[0-9abcdefABCDEF]+2f545950453d504c4d4e$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(pduString);
    return m.find() ? m.group(1) : "";
}

public String getUrl(String pduString)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^68747470[0-9abcdefABCDEF]+00$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(pduString);
    return m.find() ? m.group(1) : "";
}
```

Please let me know if you have any trouble with this code.

PS: You may need to add `+` to the number to get it on the internation format and `http://` to the url.